# How to return integer when map getOrDefault return an object

Tags: java

Let's say I have a constructor for a tire that takes two integers, `pressure` and `maxPressure`

```
public class Tire {
  private int pressure;
  private int maxPressure;
  public Tire(int pressure, int maxPressure){
    this.pressure = pressure;
    this.maxPressure = maxPressure;
  }
  public int getPressure(){return pressure;}
  public int getMaxPressure(){return maxPressure;}
}
```

In my main class I can add a new `Tire` to a `HashMap` called `tires` with a `pressure` of 25 and `maxPressure` of 32.

```
public Map<String, Tire> tires = new HashMap<>;
public int defaultTirePressure = 28;
tires.put("Goodyear", new Tire(25, 30));
```

I want to be able get the `pressure()` of the `Tire` object  if it exists or use the `defaultTirePressure`

```
//should be 25
tires.getOrDefault("Goodyear", defaultTirePressure).getPressure();

//should be 28 because there is no Michelin tire defined in tires
tires.getOrDefault("Michelin", defaultTirePressure).getPressure();
```

Obviously this does not work because `defaultTirePressure` is an integer and `tires` contains `Tire` objects.

This works, but it is kind of long:

```
//will set someTirePressure to 25
if(tires.containsKey("Goodyear")){
  someTirePressure = tires.getValue("Goodyear").getPressure();
}else{
  someTirePressure = defaultTirePressure;
}

//will set anotherTirePressure to 28 because there is no Michelin tire defined in tires
if(tires.containsKey("Michelin")){
  anotherTirePressure = tires.getValue("Goodyear").getPressure();
}else{
  anotherTirePressure = defaultTirePressure;
}
```

Is there no way to use getOrDefault in this example? I feel I may have answered my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not provide `Tire` object with default pressure in `getOrDefault` method as a default value

```
tires.getOrDefault("Michelin", new Tire(25, defaultTirePressure)).getPressure();
```

You can also have default `Tire` object

```
public final Tire defaultTire = new Tire(25,28);
tires.getOrDefault("Michelin", defaultTire).getPressure();
```

Or you can also have single argument constructor with max pressure to create deault `Tire` object

```
public Tire(int maxPressure) {
   this.maxPressure = maxPressure;
}

public final Tire defaultTire = new Tire(28);
tires.getOrDefault("Michelin", defaultTire).getPressure();
```

Comment: thanks, that works! I would probably add another constructor to Tire which accepts one integer as the pressure because there is no need to set a maxPressure here when I am only looking for the default pressure.

Comment: yes that is also best approach i will update my answer as well @LemonPickles

Answer (score 0):

Since [`HashMap#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) returns `null` for unknown keys, you could use an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

```java
final int someTirePressure = Optional.ofNullable(tires.get("Michelin"))
    .map(Tire::getPressure)
    .orElse(defaultTirePressure);
```